# SSL Protocol error with flask app

Tags: python, ssl, flask

I've been trying to run a simple flask app but I'm getting the following error.

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

I'm running it as python app.py, sudo python app.py but the same error is always popping up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
    from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
    __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
    from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
    from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 26, in <module>
    from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 94, in <module>
    import httplib
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1230, in <module>
    import ssl
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 133, in <module>
    PROTOCOL_SSLv23 = PROTOCOL_TLS
NameError: name 'PROTOCOL_TLS' is not defined
```

Help is appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Completely uninstalled python and all it's dependencies and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears to occur when a you have an outdated OpenSSL or PyOpenSSL version. Updating PyOpenSSL should fix this issue:

```
pip install --upgrade pyopenssl
```